# Compare single value against array - substitute the value for closest number within array

Tags: php, arrays, math

Title is lengthy and confusing, forgive me.

```
$array = (1,5,10,25,50);
$x = 8
```

How would I compare $x to each value within the array, and then select the value with the closest match.

In this case, it would be 10.

I imagined creating a handful of if statements but thought there could be a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way, using an intermediate array with the differences:

```
$diff = array();

foreach($array as $n)      
  $diff[$n] = abs($x - $n);  // key = number, value = difference

// get the key that contains the smallest difference
$closest = array_search(min($diff), $diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$min = 0;
foreach ($array AS $i => $v) {
  if (abs($array[$min] - $x) > abs($v - $x))
    $min = $i;
  // you can optimize this with :
  if ($v == $x)
    break;
}
$closest = $array[$min];
```

Something like that should work.